# StreamReading a file immediately after StreamWriting to that same file

Tags: c#, streamreader, race-condition, streamwriter

Given this example code:

```
1:   using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\file.txt"))
2:   {
3:       sw.WriteLine(great_string);
4:   }
5:
6:   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\file.txt"))
7:   {
8:       sr.ReadToEnd();
9:   }
```

Is it possible that the `great_string` written on line 3 would not be present in `C:\file.txt` when `StreamReader.ReadToEnd` is called on line 8?  It seems to me that it would be possible, because your average CPU works much faster than your average HDD, but I've been testing this today, and so far the string written on line 3 is always present when I read the file on line 8.  I'm thinking that maybe the `using` statement won't close the stream until all of the data is written to / read from the file, thus preventing the kind of situation that I'm asking about.

I've been reading about the [StreamWriter.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx) method on MSDN, and it states the following:

> You must call Close to ensure that all data is correctly written out to the underlying stream.

But it doesn't say WHEN the data will be written out to the underlying stream.

Thanks in advance for any info on this subject.  I did search for answers to this question, but I didn't find anything...I didn't really know what terms to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data might not be physically present on the HDD after calling Close but the system (the windows Kernel) will give the appearance that it is. And all that matters is the appearance.

If you read from the file just written Windows will either ask the HDD or serve from cache.

If this was not the case it would be hard to write reliable programs because the order of effects could change arbitrarily across functions and even processes. It would be chaos. So the system guarantees sequential consistency.

If you think about it: If this serialization property was not present a file could have multiple contents at the same time! Read it the first time and you see the old contents. Read it again and you suddenly see changes appear. This kind of behavior is not possible, fortunately.

Comment: "If this was not the case it would be hard to write reliable programs because the order of effects could change arbitrarily across functions and even processes. It would be chaos. So the system guarantees sequential consistency."  --- I was thinking a similar thing in the back of my mind, but I didn't know how to phrase it.  Thanks, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking that maybe the using statement won't close the stream
>   until all of the data is written to / read from the file, thus
>   preventing the kind of situation that I'm asking about.

Yep, exactly. using() makes sure that the object is fully disposed. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx?ppud=4 for more information on the using statement.

That said, before a file is closed it's data will be flushed out. It will, indeed, wait for the file to be written.

Answer (score 1):

alleywayjack's answer is correct. Watch the timings:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var file = @"c:\temp\test.bin";
        String huge = new String(new char[20 * 1024 * 1024]);
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        using (var stream = new StreamWriter(file))
        {
            sw2.Start();
            stream.Write(huge);
            sw2.Stop();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        sw2.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Write 20MB to cache: " + (sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds - sw2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
        Console.WriteLine("Write 20MB from cache to HD: " + sw2.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
```

Output:

```
Write 20MB to cache: 5   // ms (including preparing the stream) 
Write 20MB from cache to HD: 186   // ms
```

The whole procedure is blocking (synchronous).

Comment: Thanks for writing this.  I've just run this code, and the difference (as you've shown in your output) is very large, but not surprising.  It's cool to be able to see just how big the difference is.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.flush.aspx) instead, it ensures data to be written.

Comment: No! Flush is not meant for this use. Close is totally anough in 100% of the cases. Flush causes caches to be flushed and causes a disk seek.

Comment: @usr: Cool your jets there. `Dispose` calls `Flush` whether you like it or not (and `Close` simply calls `Dispose(true)`).

Comment: Dispose does not call Flush. You are misreading the reflected code. It calls FlushWrite which flushes FileStream internal buffers. It does not advise the OS to physically flush and cause a disk "fsync".; meta-point: calling Flush is common bad advise and I take action against it whenever I can. Some people recommend calling Close, Flush, Dispose and then close the using block. It's insane.

Comment: @usr: We're not even talking about the same thing. You are correct about `FileStream`, which is what `StreamWriter` will use based on the called constructor in the question. I was looking only at `StreamWriter` itself, which calls `Flush` on whatever stream it has. Honestly, `FileStream` is more than I cared to look through, as its flushing mechanism is extensive.

Comment: @MatthewFerreira you are right. I actually remember having been bitten by this. I was forced to write a wrapper class around Stream to prevent StreamWriter from flushing the underlying stream! This is such a nasty perf bug that is easily noticeable in certain perf tests.